# Data migration from MySQL to SQL Server is taking huge time using pandas library

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-rds

I need to migrate all our historical data from MySQL to SQL server. Data size is more then 50 GB.

I have created a script for migrate those data from MySQL to SQL server. using python Pandas library. Main reason for choosing pandas library is I am adding some cleaning process before migration.

```
def _insert_data_with_dataframe(self, df):

    if len(df) > 0:

        chunk_size = 5000

        for i in range(len(df) // chunk_size):
            df.head(n=chunk_size).to_sql('logs', self.engine_sql_staging, if_exists='append', index=False)

            df = df.iloc[chunk_size:]

            if len(logs) < chunk_size:
              logs.to_sql('logs', self.engine_sql_staging, if_exists='append', index=False)
              logs.iloc[chunk_size:]
```

I am using pandas **df.to_sql** function processing time is huge slow. To optimize this I insert those data chunk wise. But still data processing time is huge.

When I run my script in my local machine it takes **35 minutes** to process **1 million rows**.

Same script when I am running in a AWS server (I am using AWS SQL Server RDS) taking more then **half an hour** for only **50 thousands rows**.

I have checked AWS console and found instance RAM and CPU are normal. So my question is what is taking too much time for the same query in AWS server.

My SQL server version is 2016.

Comment: It's taking a lot of time *because* of Pandas. Pandas isn't an ETL tool, it loads everything into memory before trying to send it row by row to the destination. A direct connection would be a LOT faster

Comment: SQL Server *already* has a very good ETL tool, SSIS. Why don't you use it? You could even use SSMS's Import Data Wizard to **pipe** data from a MySQL or flat file source to a SQL Server destination. Or you can upload the data to a disk on Amazon and load it from there

Comment: Depending on the type of data cleansing, 35 minutes for 1M rows only is probably too much. Inserting 50K rows should take seconds, AWS or not. *Unless* you are trying to insert the data into a heavily used table, resulting in a lot of locking. Load the data into a staging table and then run a single MERGE or UPDATE/INSERT command to move the data into the production table. Bulk import tools like SSIS, the BULK INSERT command or `bcp` also use minimal logging for bulk operations. Instead of logging individual INSERT's they log only entire data pages

Comment: I have also used pentaho for the same purpose, but got same result. So I think pandas is not a problem here.

Comment: Used it to do what? If you load everything and then write it one row at a time you'll get bad performance, no matter what. Besides - why use anything at all? Why not insert the data directly? Or upload a flar file, then bulk insert it?

Comment: Finally, why *Pentaho* when you already have an ETL tool in SSIS?

Comment: I cannot insert SQL directly because I need to clean data and also add few columns with implement few logic with those data.

Comment: Yes, I read the previous comments. And SSIS does that, only a lot faster since it uses the bulk insert mechanisms. Even when you run it on the client. And you can insert the cleaned data. What you didn't explain is what you *actually* do and what is *actually* taking so long. There is no information here, except the extremely strong suspicion that the code sends INSERTs one at a time, resulting in an incredible time waste in round-trips

Comment: Or the equally strong suspicion that you are trying to upsert a live table, resulting in huge delays. As I said before, the normal approach is to put the data into a staging table and then upsert them into the final table. *NOT* try to upsert rows one by one

Comment: I am not familiar with SSIS. From beginning of my project I use pentaho and Python.

I am also confused why this taking long time. Is there any bulk insert row limitation for SQL server ?

Comment: Assume that I'm sitting on top of 80GB of data, with 30M rows and importing some 50K rows per second. Which isn't far from what I actually do right now (apart from typing). *Don't* try to upsert a live table like this. It's the code's problem and a very bad practice.

Comment: If you try to send 50K individual MERGE or UPDATE/INSERT statements, especially on a table without indexes, or if the WHERE clause doesn't use the indexes *ONLY*, the server will have to *search* and *lock* a lot of the data. It would have to take a lock on the index as well while it's updating it. On a heavily-used table *your* statement would have to wait for other active transactions to finish. Repeat 50K times, adding the network latency. Not good

Comment: That's why you *never* update a live table, especially over the internet. You insert the data into a staging/temporary table, then execute a *single* SQL statement that will UPDATE or INSERT all of the data at once. This should take *seconds* (less than 10)

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure this is gonna be faster if you try:

```
def _insert_data_with_dataframe(self, df):

    chunk_size = 5000

    df.to_sql('logs', self.engine_sql_staging, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=chunk_size)
```

Consult documentation on to_sql: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: I have used pandas default chucksize parameter, but still it takes time.

Comment: Yes, but it should be 10 mins max... at least when I use it, which aws are you using? I am on medium machine, when I was on small I remember swap memory to be a problem.

Comment: I am using a medium intense.

Comment: last try! ;) how are you declaring the engine? Use sql alchemy for that:    
    import sqlalchemy;
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(database_url)

Comment: from sqlalchemy import create_engine;

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://' + connection + '/' + staging_live)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fast_executemany=True` option in your connection engine

For example, use it as:

```
engine = create_engine(
            'mssql+pyodbc://{0}/{1}?trusted_connection=yes&driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0' \
             .format(server_name, db_name),
            fast_executemany=True
        )
```